# Evidence regarding the effect of soft-skills for academic success?

Tags: reference-request, social-skills, soft-skills

I was planning on giving a talk for undergrads regarding the effect of soft skills on success in both academia and the industry. It seems well-established that soft skills (along with hard skills) are beneficial to one's future success. I was looking for some hard evidence or references (perhaps from influential figures or studies) regarding the effect of soft skills on academic success (both as a student and after graduation). 
Reference to studies or even quotes from influential people regarding this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: This is an old reference but immensely useful.  
Advice for New Faculty Members 1st Edition
by Robert Boice (Author)  It is an eye opener on what affects the 7x different in productivity of high and low performers.

Comment: There should be a reference somewhere to academia being a community but most students don't stay on. The tips in Boice are life changin.

Comment: @jobucks can you please provide your comment as an answer so that it can be accepted?